# Issue with gcloud auth login

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to login to gcp with below command:

gcloud auth application-default login

It opens the web broweser and when I try to login to with my email id it throw the following error message:

400. That’s an error.

The server cannot process the request because it is malformed. It should not be retried. That’s all we know.

My gcp console is integrared with SSO.

Any support is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jas

Comment: Can you provide more details? On which OS are you? What's your GCLOUD version?

Comment: 1) Reboot your system. 2) Open a web browser and make sure you can log into the [console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

Comment: Actually, when I run "gcloud auth application-default" login, it is taking me to google workspace and post login it throw the malformed URL error message. I tried by restarting my machine as well. I am using RHEL 7.0 machine to run gcloud command.